# adding another unmanaged source file to my play project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I try to add another source directory to my **play** project with

```
def temporarySources = Def.setting { (baseDirectory in Compile).value / "temporary" }
```

and then add to settings

```
(unmanagedSources in Compile) += temporarySources.value
```

after running `sbt test`, sbt complains , that the directory doesn't exist, although i'm sure it is there (i can cd to the directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need `unmanagedSourceDirectories` and not `unmanagedSources`, try the following setting:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += (baseDirectory.value / "temporary"),
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test    += (baseDirectory.value / "temporary")
```